# Why does GreaterEqual take a long time to evaluate with arrays?

Tags: performance-tuning

Take the following example:

```
big = RandomReal[1, 10000000];
Head[big >= 0.66] // AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.53489, GreaterEqual} *)
```

Why does this take a long time to evaluate, given that the expression doesn't actually change?

---

**Update:**  Simon Woods points out that the slowdown is due to unpacking.  There is also some strange interaction with `ReplaceAll` that I do not understand.  Both are demonstrated by the following:

```
r=RandomReal[1,10000000];

On["Packing"]

Hold[Greater[r,0.5]]/.{x_?ArrayQ:>x}//AbsoluteTiming
Developer`FromPackedArray::unpack: Unpacking array in call to Greater.
{0.497073,Hold[r>0.5]}

Hold[greater[r,0.5]]/.{x_?ArrayQ:>x}//AbsoluteTiming
{0.000017,Hold[greater[r,0.5]]}

ArrayQ[r]//AbsoluteTiming
{3.*10^-6,True}
```

---

Note:

- `big` is a large packed array
- `big >= 0.66` is the same as `GreaterEqual[big, 0.66]`
- the result is identical to `GreaterEqual[big, 0.66]`

---

This is a problem for my BoolEval package, which has a `BoolEval` function that transforms the expression `big >= x` to `UnitStep[big - x]` to speed up element-wise comparisons.  `big >= x` takes longer to evaluate than `UnitStep[big - x]`.

Here's a much simplified version of the function:

```
greatereq[a_, b_] := UnitStep[a-b]
BoolEval[expr_] := expr /. GreaterEqual -> greatereq
```

A potential solution is

```
SetAttributes[BoolEval, HoldAll]
BoolEval[expr_] := Unevaluated[expr] /. GreaterEqual -> greatereq
```

The problem with this is that it will not work with

```
f[] := big >= 66
BoolEval[f[]]
```

Such a function would simply be too confusing to use.

Comment: @Kuba The actual function can handle arbitrary Boolean expressions such as  `0.1 < arr < 0.5 && arr != 0.4`.  This solution would hide the performance problem for a few common cases, but otherwise it will still be slow.  So I'm not fully happy with it.

Comment: Yep, seems like a dead end for a general function.

Comment: `On["Packing"]` reveals that the array is unpacked in the call to GreaterEqual

Comment: How about the `HoldAll` version but instead of `Unevaluated` use `Block[{GreaterEqual}, ...]`

Comment: @SimonWoods I thought of it but the difficulty with that is the following: What if someone does `BoolEval[myFun[] > 1]` and `myFun[]` uses `Greater`?  I am probably going to do `HoldAll` and require the boolean expressions and comparisons to appears explicitly in the argument.  I.e. `BoolEval[x > 1]` is okay, but `fun[]:=x>1; BoolEval[fun[]]` is not.  However, I am not willing to break `BoolEval[myFun[] > 1]` as well.

Comment: What "strange interaction with `ReplaceAll`" are you observing?  The unpacking?  That comes from `ArrayQ[Greater[r, 0.5]]`.  Can we directly overload all boolean operators and apply those within your call, `Block[{Greater = myGreater, Less = myLess}, body]`?  Make them *general* and `myFun[] > 1` should still work, right?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I more or less gave up on this question, partly because WRI explained why there's unpacking (and it's unlikely to go away), and partly because I don't think I was taking the correct approach anyway.  You are right about the `ReplaceAll`—embarrassing oversight.  I don't think `Block` will be a good approach, but too little space to explain here ... I wanted to entirely rewrite BoolEval and blog about it.  We can discuss next week in chat if you're interested, otherwise I'll ping you when the blog is out.

Comment: I look forward to either eventuality. :-)

Comment: @Szabolcs the classic definition pattern I've seen is to use `HoldAll`, a basic definition respecting this `HoldAll`, and one that evaluates to check anything not matching this form: i.e. define `BE[ a_ > b_ ]  := greater[a, b]` and then `BE[ e_ ] /; !TrueQ[$inBE] := Block[{$inBE=True, res}, res = BE[Evaluate@e] /; Head[res] =!= BE ]`. Unfortunately this would  probably confuse users who notice performance differences between `BE[ a > b]` and `BE[ f[] ]` for `f[] := a > b`